# Text appearing before Doctype?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We've two servers in our SharePoint 2010 environment. Load balanced.
For some reason on one of them there is text appearing before the DocType tag.

Any ideas how to hunt do where it's coming from?

Thanks
P

Comment: What Load Balancing Method/Appliance are you using, Maybe there is some re-write rule set up for that server.

Answer (score 1):

Load the page and right click on the rogue text, click "inspect" (browser dependant)

I'd start by recording the page loading and using the timeline in chrome. You can inspect the moment that the text is inserted, this may give you a clue as to where it is being pulled from, also make note of any external classes this text may have.

Best of luck!